# PHP PDO Sending emails to multiple email address not working

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

This is my code in sending email. In this code, if the email address is recipient of multiple data issue, the data will be put together in one email, instead of receiving one email per issue. My problem is if I have multiple email address I included in the email address textbox, the data is not inserting in the database. What should I do?

```
function InsertEmailMessage() {
$explode_check=explode(',', $_POST['ticked']);
//print_r($explode_check);
//$to[]= $row6['PersoninCharge'];

$messages = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($explode_check);$i++)
{
    $Selcheckb=$explode_check[$i];

    $sql6 = "SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice WHERE ID=:cb";
    $conn = dbConnect();
    $stmt6->bindParam(':cb', $Selcheckb);
    $stmt6 = $conn->prepare($sql6);
    $stmt6->execute();

    $data = $stmt6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //var_dump($data);

    foreach ($data as $row6) {

        $invnumb=$row6['Invoice_Number'];
        $partnumb=$row6['Part_Number'];
        $issue=$row6['Issues'];
        $pic=$row6['PIC_Comments'];
        $issuetype=$row6['Issue_Type'];
        $createdate=$row6['Creation_Date'];
        $site=$row6['Site'];
        $vendor=$row6['Vendor_Name'];
        $invdate=$row6['Invoice_Date'];
        $po=$row6['PO'];
        $rr=$row6['RR'];
        $currency=$row6['Currency'];
        $invamount=$row6['Invoice_Amount'];
        $stat=$row6['Status'];
        $to[]=$row6['PersoninCharge'];
        $emailadd=explode(",", $to);


        if($row6['Status']=="Open") {
            if(!isset($messages[$emailadd])) {
              $messages[$emailadd] = '';
            }

            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Issue Type: {$issuetype} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Creation Date: {$createdate} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Site: {$site} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Vendor Name: {$vendor} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Invoice Date: {$invdate} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Invoice Number: {$invnumb} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Part Number:</b><br>{$partnumb}<br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>PO: {$po} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>RR: {$rr} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Currency: {$currency} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Invoice Amount: {$invamount} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Issues:</b><br>{$issue}<br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Status: {$stat} </b><br><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>{$pic}<b><br>";
            $messages[$emailadd] .= "<br><br>";

        }
    }
}

foreach($messages as $email=>$message) {
    dbInsertEmailMessage($email, "Invalid Invoice Tracking Message", "<html>{$message}</html>");
    echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Email sent to {$email}.')</script>";
}

$conn=null;
}


function dbInsertEmailMessage($send_to, $subject, $message) {

        $sql7 = "INSERT INTO email_queue (send_to, subject, message) 
            VALUES (:send_to, :subject, :message)"; 
        $conn = dbConnect();
        $stmt7 = $conn->prepare($sql7); 
        $stmt7->bindParam(':send_to', $send_to);
        $stmt7->bindParam(':subject', $subject);
        $stmt7->bindParam(':message', $message);
        $stmt7->execute();
        $conn=null; 
        }
```

Comment: Your `InsertEmailMessage()` function does too many things. A function should only do one. Split `InsertEmailMessage()` up and check each function idependantly.

Comment: I advise you to use unnamed parameters `?`and use lazy binding passing data into execute. [see]( http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)